# Global inbox acting differently with per-site meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, per-site-meta

When I look at my global inbox on meta.math.stackexchange.com, I only see notifications from meta.math.stackexchange.com. When I look at my inbox on primary sites, I don't see the meta.math notifications.

**Edit**: Upon further investigation, it looks like this works correctly in meta.gaming.stackexchange.com, so maybe it is just a problem with meta.math?

The two screenshots below were taken a few seconds apart:

[image]
Global inbox for StackOverflow

[image]
Global inbox for Meta.Math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there's a bug picking up your associations (and thus your global inbox) from meta accounts.

A fix has been pushed to dev, and will be deployed sometime today.  You'll probably need to logout and login (once this is deployed), to force an account sync (or wait until it happens automatically*).

<sub>*Profile changes, etc. trigger this with about an hour lag time.</sub>